# External exception is thrown in function when using DLL's from not application folder

Tags: delphi, exception, dll, delphi-2009

I have a problem which I do not understand. I am using a DLL in my application. This DLL requires other DLL's and I have all of them. If I put the libraries in my appliction folder everything works fine.

However, having a bunch of DLLs in application folder looks quite ugly so I wanted to move them to application\lib subfolder.

After this change now I am getting External Exception when I try to use some of its functions.

I've only changed one line of code:

The original code

```
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(Pchar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'External.dll'))
```

The code after change

```
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary(Pchar(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'lib\External.dll'))
```

In both cases `DLLHandle` have a handle after loading the library. I am also not getting any error after calling `GetProcAddress(  DLLHandle, '_SomeFunction@8')`

No exceptions, and return value of `GetLastError` is always 0.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Life is far easier if you keep the DLLs in the same folder as the executable. That's the [first folder searched](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when libraries are loaded. To move all the DLLs into a sub folder of the executable directory requires cooperation from all DLLs.

Most likely you have secondary DLL dependencies that are not cooperating. So exe loads A fine, but then A fails to load B. You can debug this further with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) running in profile mode. It's quite possible that a secondary DLL is being loaded with implicit linking and that this throws and exception. Whatever the cause, Depenency Walker will lead you to the problem.

Whilst you can modify the PATH variable this is generally not advisable. If you do choose to go down this route then don't modify system wide, just modify the executable process environment at runtime before the first LoadLibrary. This is tenable so long as all your DLL linking is explicit using GetProcAddress.

All accepted wisdom recommends that you put your DLLs in the same folder as your executable. I would echo this recommendation. If you did this then you would be able to use implicit linking which would greatly simplify your code.

Yet another option may be to abandon DLLs and link everything straight into your executable. Unless you have a plugin type architecture, a single big exe is by far the simplest approach.

Comment: Thank you David but as I've said earlier in comments. Even setting system-wide Path for dlls did not solve the problem. I will check this issue by the Dependency Walker, never heard of it before. If it will be helpful I mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The other DLL's that need to be loaded must be on the system path for Windows to find them. Your application can find the External.dll as you explicitly define the path. Try adding the lib folder to your system path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately adding folder to system path did not help.

Comment: system path will likely make it work but it's not a very pleasant option

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis, but please don't mess with my system path without permission, you can also register the dll with windows so it knows where to find it without going through the path. Should be faster as well. (Made this a comment because I can't remember where/how to register the dll and no time to go hunting for it).

Comment: @marjan there is dll redirection and sxs manifests but they are probably gross overkill in this situation

Comment: @marjan, you can register a dll with `regsvr32 c:\path_to_dll\dll-name.dll` But that's only for dll's with COM(OLE) interfaces in them, not just any dll.

Comment: @Johan I presume that Marjan meant [DLL Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, that's what I meant. Thanks for the link!